# Array with random images using on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, onclicklistener

I have created an array which shows random images when I press on a button, and every picture has `onclick` action.

I want the `onclick` action to display an alert when i click on the image that i want but I'm not sure how do i fix my code?

EDIT1:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<script src = "ProjectJ.js"></script>
   </head>

  <body>


  </body>
  <form name="imageForm">
  <table border=3>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input onclick="displayImage0();" type=button value="Display Random Image">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img  src="batman.jpg" name="img"  onclick="displayImage()"/>
      <img  src="bell.jpg" name="img1"  onclick="displayImage1()"/>
      <img  src="candy.jpg" name="img2"  onclick="displayImage2()"/>
      </td>
      <tr>
      <td>
      <img  src="shirt.jpg" name="img3"  onclick="displayImage3()"/>
       <img  src="chess.jpg" name="img4"  onclick="displayImage4()"/>
        <img  src="flower.jpg" name="img5"  onclick="displayImage5()"/>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
         <img  src="horse.jpg" name="img6"  onclick="displayImage6()"/>
          <img  src="key.jpg" name="img7"  onclick="displayImage7()"/>
           <img  src="horse.jpg" name="img8"  onclick="displayImage8()"/>
           </td>
           </tr>

  </tr>
  </table>
</form>






 </html>
```

**JS**

```
var imagesArray = ["batman.jpg", "bell.jpg", "candy.jpg", "chess.jpg", "flower.jpg", "horse.jpg", "key.jpg","shirt.jpg","tower.jpg"];



function displayImage0(){


    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9); 
    document.img.src = imagesArray[num];
     var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)
    document.img1.src = imagesArray[num];
     var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)
    document.img2.src = imagesArray[num];
     var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)
    document.img3.src = imagesArray[num];
     var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)
    document.img4.src = imagesArray[num];
     var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)
    document.img5.src = imagesArray[num];
     var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)
    document.img6.src = imagesArray[num];
     var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)
    document.img7.src = imagesArray[num];
     var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)
    document.img8.src = imagesArray[num];
     var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)


}
function displayImage(){


    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);

    document.img.src = imagesArray[num];


}


function displayImage1(){


    if (document.img1.src=="flower.jpg")
    {
    window.alert("FLOWER!");
    }
    //alert when clicked and flower is here


}

function displayImage2(){

 //alert messsage when clicked and tower is here


}


function displayImage3(){

 // alert message when clicked and key is here


}
function displayImage4(){

  //alert mesasge when clicked and horse is here

}

function displayImage5(){

// alert message when clicked and chess is here


}

function displayImage6(){

// alert message when clicked and shirt is here


}

function displayImage7(){

// alert message when clickd and batman is here


}

function displayImage8(){

   // alert message when and candy is here


}
```

Comment: Remove all but the 1st `var` in displayImage0(). What other problems do you face? DisplayImage1 looks OK

Comment: @Gavriel it doesnt show the alert when the flower image comes up and i press on it

Comment: Then debug it by adding: `alert(document.img1.src);` as well to the function. What did it show?

Comment: it says the location of the flower image but stil it doesnt say "FLOWER!"

Comment: The onclick for the flower image calls `displayImage5()` however your code for alerting if it is a flower is in `displayImage1()`

Comment: Yes because the flower will appear 1 eventually because it keeps giving random pictures till appears and then after you click on the flower you should get an alert

Answer (score 0):

The `onclick` for the flower image calls `displayImage5()` however your code for alerting if it is a flower is in `displayImage1()`

Comment: But he's first clicking at "Display Random Image" button, and then he clicks on the image that displays the flower.

Answer (score 0):

I asked you what did document.img1.src alert! The reason it never alerts "FLOWER" is because when you assign "flower.jpg" to the img.src, and you read it back it gives you the full URL:

```js
document.img1.src = "flower.jpg";
alert("Lesson1: '"+ document.img1.src + "' != 'flower.jpg'");


if (document.img1.src=="flower.jpg") {
  window.alert("FLOWER!");
} else {
  window.alert("NOT FLOWER!");
}

if (document.img2.src=="http://example.com/cow.jpg") {
  window.alert("COW!");
}

document.img2.src = "http://example.com/cat.jpg";
if (document.img2.src=="http://example.com/cat.jpg") {
  window.alert("CAT!");
}
```

```html
<img src="bell.jpg" name="img1"/>
<img src="http://example.com/cow.jpg" name="img2"/>
```

Comment: Well any advice what to write in the if statement because I have tried everything with the .src

Comment: My advice is to use full URL-s instead of "flower.jpg". Everywhere! Where you assign it to src, and where you compare it. Just change the array to have "http://example.com/foo/bar/flower.jpg",... in it, and make sure you also compare with the full urls

Comment: You made a mistake. See my demo now, it clearly shows it works.